# Sending Google+ Hybrid server-side flow one time authorization code over HTTP Safe?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, curl, google-plus

Hello I am going to be switching from using googles Client-side flow to the 
Hybrid server-side flow because before the client would be sent a access_token which I was then going to send to the server to then verify the user before logging them in or creating a new account for them but since I can't get cors to work with https, I can not safely send it.

I looked over the different ways and it seems the Hybrid server-side flow is the one I wanted all along anyways, **the only question I have is, is it safe to send the one time authorization code over http using ajax?**

I figure it is since it is only usable once and once the server uses it which would be over https using curl, it no longer has any value anyways. The access_token would then only ever be on the server and never have been on the client which seems much more secure then the old way of using the client side flow.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The short answer is: **absolutely not**

The longer answer depends on level of risk and what risk you're willing to accept, but in general it seems like a bad idea. It assumes that the either the connection between client and server has a low chance of being intercepted or manipulated, or that the information being protected by oauth is of incredibly low value that nobody would ever try. Neither of these seem like safe prospects.

For example, and purely offhand, it would not be difficult for a rogue router in between client and server to intercept the request (if it knew about the likelihood of it) and use the client code itself first. This could cause all sorts of problems on both your server and client which could take a while to resolve... during which the rogue has access to whatever service was being authorized. There are other scenarios, similar to this one, which could be equally problematic.

The better question is - why do you want to do this? Is there a reason you're not willing to setup an SSL server, even one with a self-signed certificate?

Comment: Just to add onto what Prisoner said. If your site is not SSL exclusively, any hardware between the client and server can inject JavaScript and send the code to their own server.

Comment: I guess I am just going have to bite the bullet and get cors with ssl working cause that was the reason I figured this might be better but i did have my doubts which turned out to be right, lol. Thanks